# Thread explanation

Tags: java, multithreading

I just wanna know what does each line mean? Because I like studying codes first before using them to manipulate them easier and for me to also learn

This is a java code

```
1. ----> class ShowTask extends Thread { 
2. ---->     @Override 
3. ---->          public void run() { 
4. ---->               try { 
                            .................
5. ---->                   }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          }
                         }
                        }
```

What does 1,2,3,4,5 do?

Comment: I don't see anything related to sleep here.

Comment: oh yeah sorry the .... was supposed to be the sleep code based from my question yesterday, i've erased it to make the code simpler because I already understood that part sorry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line by line, here's what the do:

1. Declares a class named `ShowTask` that extends class `Thread` (presumably the built-in Java class `java.lang.Thread`).
2. Annotates the next member of `ShowTask` as overriding a base class method.
3. Declares the `run()` method of class `ShowTask`. This is the target of the annotation.
4. Begins a try/catch block
5. Catches any `InterruptedException` that might be thrown by the body of the `try` block. If the body throws an `InterruptedException`, the `try` block will immediately stop executing and the body of the `catch` block (which is empty in your code) will begin executing. The variable `e` will be bound to the exception that was thrown.

Comment: Thanks man this is everything I need to know

Answer (score 1):

Every thing is described here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html

Answer (score 0):

You should read up a book on Java for beginners to have your questions answered

Comment: Thanks, i've bought a programming book by joyce farrell and i've learned so much about it. I'm gonna buy more books after I finish it thanks